# can I view two separate aspx files in one webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an issue where I have two pages that deal with very similar things and as such quite a few of their methods and aspx server controls have identical method names and variables.  In short, it's pretty obvious that the code was copy/pasted and the innards were merely altered.  I have a pending request that the two pages be merged so I've explored a number of options as to how I should best merge them.

First I thought that perhaps I could put one of the pages in a masterpage that will allow for a content place holder wherein I'd then put the code/controls, but it looked to be a bad idea once I started to make plans. For one the similar names would probably still be a problem and second it seems a rather clunky way to merge two pages together.

I've considered renaming all the methods and controls but on the other hand it's going to take a lot of time picking over the code and the controls to rename them all.  My worry is that if I try to change the problematic method names, controls, IDs, I'll introduce a lot of bugs in the code.

Is there a better way to view two pages in one webpage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so with iFrames. But I think the website gets better maintaining with .net controls (.ascx files), and then calling them in a new page

Comment: Thanks, this answer got me to investigate user controls, which I can see a lot of uses for.

Answer (score 2):

That thing is called `user control`.

[UserControl class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.aspx)
read [this](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/using/) official tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I think there can be 3 options that will work for you:
1. Put all common stuff in a user control and use it in both pages. This is the most straight forward solution and this is the main reason user controls exist - reuse of both UI and code behind. This is most likely the best option.
2. Have a utility class that will contain all common methods. The disadvantage of this solution is that you will only share code, not UI.
3. You can have a BasePage that inherits from Page, and have both pages inherit from BasePage. Again, you will shared only the code, not the UI. This is usually a good solution when you want to add some functionality for all your web pages.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for ASP.Net Web Forms have you checked out [Nested Master Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/nested-master-pages-cs), not merely a single MastPage?

If you have a common Theme or layout this goes in the *Base* MasterPage, your *nested* MasterPage then exposes common UI controls, Events Handlers etc that are common between the next group of Pages (the layer you referred to), your final ASPX Page then exposes the individual page functionality that is different between the ASPX Pages, UI controls, Events etc for each unique page.

By using the [@ MasterType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx) page declaration you ASPX Page has a strongly typed reference to one or all MasterPages which would allow the ASPX page to easily access methods and properties of the common MasterPage.